# How to Multi-Select options on a drop down menu on a web using Blue Prism

Tags: multi-select, blueprism

I am trying to get blue prism to multi-select some options on a webpage. What I did was spy the html combo box and then use navigate to create four elements:

1. Global send keys, with text value = "`<{CTRL}>`".
2. Global Mouse click, with text value = option name
3. repeat 2 on other options I want to choose
4. Global send keys, with text value = "`{CTRL}`".

Error message was "Keyword "CTRL" is not valid". Very confused on how to proceed...

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but if you are interacting with a combobox, you usually can do it using a navigate stage and using the 'Select item' action.

Comment: Yes but I want to select multiple items at the same time, your solution would only select one

Comment: Can you provide a snapshot of the combobox? I have yet to come across one where you could select multiple items from. Maybe it's a listbox instead?

Comment: @Jerry, it was probably not a standard SELECT dropdown, I'm guessing it was built upon some JS framework. I quite often face those, select2 elements being a nice example. I prefer to automate those with JS injections, though.

Comment: @MarekStejskal I see. Thanks for letting me know :) But yea, I can't say I have come across those yet.

Comment: @MarekStejskal You are right, and we ended up invoking JavaScript in blue prism to multi-select..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do press a key, then do some actions, then release the key, then `Global Send Keys` is not the function to use. Go for `Global Send Key Events`.

The `<` and `>` function as a state modifier, using these you specify what key event you want to do. The character `<` is for key pressing, `>` is for releasing. So, to press Control, you would use `<{CTRL}` and to release it you would use `>{CTRL}`.